# waiting array of urls after uploading images to firebase storage and then stroing it again to firestore

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

```
const sendImageToFirebase = (e) => {
    const promises = []
    const urlsArray = []
    // productimage is an array of image files
    productImage.forEach((image, i) => {
        var storageRef = firebase.storage().ref();
        var uploadTask = storageRef.child(`${userDetailsFirebase.uid}/` + Math.random()).put(image);
        promises.push(uploadTask.on('state_changed',
            (snapshot) => {
            },
            (error) => {
                console.log("error");
            },
            async () => {
                const downloadurl = await uploadTask.snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL()
                urlsArray.push(downloadurl)
            }
        ))
    })
    Promise.all(promises).then(res => {
        db.collection("products").doc(idGeneratedforProduct).set(
            {
                imageURL: urlsArray, //array of image urls
            },
        ).then(e => {
        }).catch(error => console.log("Error while sendig items to Firebase"))
    })
}
```

I want to upload a multiple images to firebase storage. Here, sendImagToFirebase is a normal function in reactJs, and productimage is an array of image files. I want to wait for URL for each image files and then store all of them as an array to firestore. I would appreciate your input on how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a function that receoves the `ref` and the `file` and returns the `downloadURL`. By calling it for each file with a `Promise.all` you get as result your array of `downloadURL`s:

```js
const uploadFileAndGetDownloadURL = async (ref, file) => {
  const snap = await ref.put(file);
  const downloadURL = await snap.ref.getDownloadURL();

  return downloadURL;
};

const sendImageToFirebase = async (e) => {
  const promises = [];
  productImage.forEach((image, i) => {
    var storageRef = firebase.storage().ref();
    var ref = storageRef.child(`${userDetailsFirebase.uid}/` + Math.random());
    promises.push(uploadFileAndGetDownloadURL(ref, image));
  });

  //Your array with the urls
  const urlsArray = await Promise.all(promises);
};
```